# XMLHttpRequest cannot load, No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript

[image]

We are getting an error while posting to salesforce WebToLead from local javascript:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load
https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are combining locally-hosted and salesforce-hosted assets on the same page for your testing, you can tell the browser to ignore content security policy:

Mac:

```
$ /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --disable-web-security
```

Windows:

```
$ C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

All the same, the WebToLead function may not normally allow any kind of cross origin access from the browser like that. Best thing is to POST the form as intended.